# How many minutes have passed since the Unix Epoch?

Tags: date

How many minutes have passed since the Unix Epoch ? It should be January 1, 1970 ?

Let's say approximately until 1 Jan 2011... 5 865 696 000 minutes ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Minutes since Epoch until now:
((minutes=$(date +%s)/60))

# Minutes since Epoch until Jan 1 2011:
((minutes=$(date -d 'Jan 1 2011' +%s)/60))
```

Comment: The `%s` in `date +%s` is a GNU extension. Other implementations typically allow the same format strings as in `strftime(3)`, which mostly don't have `%s`. And **WHY** do everybody assume `bash` availability?

Comment: Does this take leap seconds into account?

Comment: @mattdm> From `info date`... **%s** *"...Leap seconds are not counted unless leap second support is available."* ... **%S** *"second ('00'...60').  This may be '60' if leap seconds are supported."*  ... I can only assume that it would include those seconds in a total of 'seconds-since-epoch' when the support is available.

Comment: @mattbianco 1) i didn't necessarily "assume" bash availability. I provided _my_ solution using bash. It doesn't have to be accepted by @patrick as the answer and you can provide your own solution. 2) When discussing Linux, it's almost certain that bash is available. I'd put my guess at about 99.9% likely given any random selection of Linux installations. 3) I use OSX and `%s` is available in BSD's `date` even though, in general, it's a significantly command than GNU's `date`.

Answer (score 3):

If you've got Python installed then you can run this:

```
python -c "import time; print time.time() / 60"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the online version of Unix Epoch: [Epoch Converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/). You can get the current Epoch value and also convert time back to epoch